# Good books to read

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, resource-recommendations, astrophysics

I still regard myself as a beginner in the field of physics.. And there are a lot of information I should know, I am in my second year physics, and I need to read books which are not hard to understand and are useful and enjoyable.. Any suggestions? (Doesn't depend on the included tags below)

Comment: This year I'll have Particle Physics by a special solicitude to my faculty, and I have been studying Quantum Mechanics by my own, and I find that the most useful and enjoyable way to learn is the course The Theoretical Minimum from the professor Leonard Susskind (videos), which includes a QM book written by him as a guide. This videos includes Analytical Mechanics, General Relativity, String Theory, etc.. :)

Comment: I found *Hitchhikers Guide to the Galaxy*, *Jurassic Park* and *Lord of the Rings* to be good books to read.